# error: libxml2 is required (modsecurity)

Tags: mod-security

I am trying to install `mod_security` from source. when i run `./configure` I get this error:

```
configure: error: libxml2 is required
```

After that error, I executed this command:

```
yum install libxml2
```

It installed libxml2 properly. However, I'm still getting the same error from `./configure`.  How can I resolve this error?

Comment: In another question you mentioned using CentOS. Why are you installing from source when you could have just done `yum install mod_security`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you build software, you need the library development package, not the shared library package.  So, install `libxml2-devel` and your build problems should go away (or at least the error message will change).

Comment: Thank You Sir. it worked and mod security configured. thumbs up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix your compile problem, however there is an RPM for mod_security available here:
http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/development/source/SRPMS/mod_security-2.5.7-1.fc11.src.rpm

Comment: That particular RPM may not work, given that the OS and version being used wasn't mentioned.